# How to scroll to a specific component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built a website using React (without any HTML) and I've split every page into smaller components. Let's say that I have for example the main page, and in the first component (the main section which is located at the top of the page) I have a button, and when I click on it I want it to take me to the last component of the page (which is located at the very bottom). I want something similar to the HTML "on click scroll to ID element".

How can I achieve that? Keep in mind that for every component I've created a separate js file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using react hooks. You have to refactor the last component a bit, as to forward a `ref`. You can expose the scroll method in the `LastComp` with  [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook.

#### LastComp.js

```
import { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef, useRef } from "react";

const LastComp = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const compRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    scrollIntoView: () => {
      compRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
    }
  }));
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "600px", backgroundColor: "gray" }} ref={compRef}>
      Body of the last component
    </div>
  );
});

export default LastComp;
```

In the FirstComp you can pass the ref as `refToLastComp` and call the method we exposed in the `LastComp`.

#### FirstComp.js

```
const FirstComp = ({ refToLastComp }) => {
  const scrolltoLast = () => {
    if (refToLastComp.current) {
      refToLastComp.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "600px",
        backgroundColor: "tomato"
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={scrolltoLast}>Scroll to Last</button>
      First
    </div>
  );
};

export default FirstComp;
```

On the main page, you can create and pass a new ref to `LastComp` and `FirstComp`.

#### Main.js

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import FirstComp from "./FirstComp";
import SecondComp from "./SecondComp";
import LastComp from "./LastComp";

export default function Main() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <FirstComp refToLastComp={ref} />
      <SecondComp />
      <LastComp ref={ref} />
    </>
  );
}
```

It doesn't matter where the component is located, it can be anywhere on the home page. when you click on the button it will scroll to the component to view (using [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)).

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-clarke-06eng?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Tomuta Razvan, let me know If you have any issues?

Comment: The problem is that the first component and the last component are located in separate js files and they are rendered by another js file (which renders all the components of the current page). My main.js file looks something like this:        ``return (
        
            <>
                <HomeMain />
                <HomeServices />
                <WhyUs />
                <HomeForm />
                <HomeReview />
            </>
        
    )``    I want to press a button that's located in the "HomeMain" component to take me down to the "HomeForm" component.

Comment: Then this Main js file is similar to the one you mentioned as "another js file". Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry about how the code looks like, but I don't know how to edit it to look cleaner here.

Comment: can you update the question with related code? I will update my answer.

Comment: By "another js file" I meant that every small component is located in a different js file and that I have another component (main.js file) that renders all the components together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241460/discussion-between-tomuta-razvan-and-amila-senadheera).

Comment: @Tomuta Razvan, I have updated the answer now. Please check it and mark this as the answer if it actually solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add link to the page element

```
<Link to="/page#elementid">Go</Link>
```

Do like this, in your page component

```
componentDidMount() {
    let target = window.location.hash;
    target && document.querySelector(target).scrollIntoView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to name every component by unique id.

> let scroll_to = document.getElementById("conponent_id").offsetTop;
> window.scrollTo({
> behavior: "smooth",
> top: scroll_to,
> });

onclick button just run this code